# Discord using slash commands to do "setMute()"

Tags: discord, discord.js

My code is this.

```
 client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if(!interaction.isCommand()) {
    return
  }
  const {commandName, options} = interaction
  if(commandName == 'mute') {
    const name = interaction.options.getUser('target')
    //await interaction.guild.members.voice.setMute(target);
    //name.voice.setMute(true)
    interaction.reply({
      content: 'muted',
      ephemeral: true,
    })
  }
})
```

I am inspired by the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/parsing-options.html#command-options). It took me 4 hours to try fixing it, but it still went wrong. Can someone help ?

[image]

Comment: What went wrong? what does not work in your code? Can you explain what you expected and what happens instead?

Comment: @Mirco0 I failed because I don't figure out the difference between guild member and user, but now I knew. Thank you for inspiring me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getUser method returns a User object but the setMute function is a method of GuildMember
The Guild.ban method can take a User object as parameter

```js
const User = interaction.options.getUser('target')
interaction.guild.members.fetch(User)
    .then(Member => {
        Member.voice.mute()
           .then(() => {
                interaction.reply() // Success: Your message here
            })
           .catch(err => {
                interaction.reply() // Failed: Your message here
           })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        interaction.reply() // Member not found: Your message here
    })
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I confused guild member with user yesterday, and that is the problem.